# Dagger2 injects null object

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm new to Dagger and trying to use dagger2 for DI, but looks like it injected a null presenter to my activity. Below is my codes.

public class TasksActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Inject
TasksContract.Presenter mTasksPresenter;
......

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ... ...

    DaggerTasksComponent.builder()
            .appComponent(MyApp.getAppComponent())
            .tasksModule(new TasksModule())
            .build()
            .inject(this);

   ... ...
}
```

Module for TasksActivity:

```
 @Module
    public class TasksModule {

    @Provides
    @ActivityScoped
    TasksContract.Presenter providePresenter(TaskDataRepository taskDataRepository, TasksContract.View view) {
        return new TasksPresenter(taskDataRepository, view);
    }

    @Provides
    @ActivityScoped
    TasksContract.View provideView() {
        return new TasksFragment();
    }
}
```

Component for TasksActivity:

```
@ActivityScoped
    @Component (modules = TasksModule.class, dependencies = AppComponent.class)
    public interface TasksComponent {
        void inject(TasksActivity activity);
    }
```

I also have an AppModule and AppComponent for application level dependency injection such as TaskDataRepository. And annotated them with @Singleton.

Comment: does dagger throw an exception? is your build successful? did you provide your repository and view properly?

Answer (score 2):

Create a constructor on your TaskModule passing this parameters taskDataRepository and view, then use that on your TaskModule. So your initialization should look like this

```
  DaggerTasksComponent.builder()
            .appComponent(MyApp.getAppComponent())
            .tasksModule(new TasksModule(taskDataRepository, view))
            .build()
            .inject(this);
```

Comment: Why do i have to pass taskDataRepository and view to TaskModule's constructor? I already provide taskDataRepository in AppComponent and add AppComponent as denpencies to TasksComponent. Also provide view in TaskModule. Isn't it dagger's job to find all necessary dependencies (taskDataRepository and view)? I thought that's why we use dagger2.

Comment: Your presenter returns null because your passing a null object which is your view and taskDataRepository.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide your repository and view to your module in order for injection to work. there are 2 ways to do it in your case:

1. use module parameter(not advised)

   ```
   @Module
   public class TasksModule {

   private final TaskDataRepository taskDataRepository;
   private final TasksContract.View view;

   public TasksModule(TaskDataRepository taskDataRepository, TasksContract.View view){
   this.taskDataRepository = taskDataRepository;
   this.view = view;
   ```

   }

   ```
   @Provides
   @ActivityScoped
   TasksContract.Presenter providePresenter(TaskDataRepository taskDataRepository, TasksContract.View view) {
       return new TasksPresenter(taskDataRepository, view);
   }

   @Provides
   @ActivityScoped
   TasksContract.View provideView() {
       return new TasksFragment();
   }
   ```

   }

and then your activity code for building component will look like:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ... ...

    DaggerTasksComponent.builder()
        .appComponent(MyApp.getAppComponent())
        .tasksModule(new TasksModule(new TaskDataRepository(), new TasksFragment()))
        .build()
        .inject(this);

      ... ...
    }
```

2. Use `@BindsInstance` annotation (preferred):

In order to use bindsInstance you change your activity component a bit:

```
@ActivityScoped
@Component (modules = TasksModule.class, dependencies = AppComponent.class)
public interface TasksComponent {
    void inject(TasksActivity activity);

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance Builder taskRepository(TaskDataRepository taskDataRepository);
        @BindsInstance Builder activity(TaskActivity activity);
        TasksComponent build();
  }
}
```

since we are using bindsInstance annotation we can change our module methods to static too:

```
@Module
public abstract class TasksModule {

@Provides
@ActivityScoped
static TasksContract.Presenter providePresenter(TaskDataRepository taskDataRepository, TasksContract.View view) {
    return new TasksPresenter(taskDataRepository, view);
}

@Provides
@ActivityScoped
static TasksContract.View provideView() {
    return new TasksFragment();
}
}
```

and lastly your component builder will look like this:

```
DaggerTasksComponent.builder()
    .appComponent(MyApp.getAppComponent())
    .activity(this)
    .taskRepository(new TaskDataRepository())
    .build()
    .inject(this);
```

for further reading please refer to [docs](https://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide.html#binding-instances) and other [samples](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=2ahUKEwjr8-S1hdrcAhUFr48KHW_qCfgQFjACegQICBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fproandroiddev.com%2Fdagger-2-component-builder-1f2b91237856&usg=AOvVaw1Qs8Y0dtTSF2V7O53-RsEj)

hope it helped

Comment: For the solution 1, I already have an AppComponent which looks like this:  @Component(modules = AppModule.class)
@Singleton
public interface AppComponent {
    TaskDataRepository taskDataRepository();
} and I added it as dependencies for TasksComponent, why I have to manually pass a TaskDataRepository object to TasksComponent constructor?

Comment: you don't have to. my mistake I did not see that in question.
but still you can use it as example